# Are large banks required to write blueprints on how to break them up in case they go bankrupt in the United States?

Tags: united-states, finance

Are large banks required to write blueprints on how to break them up in case they go bankrupt? I remember there was a talk about requiring large banks to write blueprint on how to break them up in case they go bankrupt to solve the problem of 'too big to fail' and I am wondering if this is now a legal requirement for large banks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was passed as part of the [Dodd-Frank Act of 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodd%E2%80%93Frank_Wall_Street_Reform_and_Consumer_Protection_Act),  Pub.L. 111–203.  The provision for so-called "resolution plans", informally called "living wills", is in the US Code at [12 USC 5365](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCODE-2019-title12/html/USCODE-2019-title12-chap53-subchapI-partC-sec5365.htm), subsection (d).  It applies to large "bank holding companies" and "nonbank financial companies".  The plans are to include:

> (A) information regarding the manner and extent to which any insured
> depository institution affiliated with the company is adequately
> protected from risks arising from the activities of any nonbank
> subsidiaries of the company;
>
> (B) full descriptions of the ownership structure, assets, liabilities,
> and contractual obligations of the company;
>
> (C) identification of the cross-guarantees tied to different
> securities, identification of major counterparties, and a process for
> determining to whom the collateral of the company is pledged; and
>
> (D) any other information that the Board of Governors and the
> Corporation jointly require by rule or order.

The Federal Reserve has more information at https://www.federalreserve.gov/supervisionreg/resolution-plans.htm, including the plans submitted by the banks.  For instance, [Citigroup's 2021 plan](https://www.federalreserve.gov/supervisionreg/resolution-plans/citigroup-1g-20210701.pdf).